# Огранизовать рациональный вывод (Категория -> содержимoе, Категория2 -> содержимoе)

Tags: while, php, foreach, mysql

Добрый день!

Не соображу, как наиболее рационально реализовать вывод.

Есть таблица с категориями, есть таблица с документами (у каждого документа есть id категории).

Нужно вывести следущим способом:

Категория 1:

- Документ, у которого прописан id данной категории.
- Документ 2, у которого прописан id данной категории.
- ....

Категория 2:

- Документ, у которого прописан id данной категории.
- Документ 2, у которого прописан id данной категории.
- ....

Как сие реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function category($document) {
  $result = array();
  foreach($document as $value) {
    $result[$value['cat']][] = $value;
  }
return $result;
}
$_document = $category(массив документов полученный из таблицы документы);
```

В итоге получишь вот такой массив. $document = array(M1=>array(0=>document, 1=>document, ..., n=>document),M2=>array(0=>document, ..., n=>document), ..., Mn=>array())

запросом получишь все категории которые используются в документах и через foreach выведешь
$cat - твой массив полученный из таблицы категории

```
foreach($cat as $value) {
      echo $value['name_category'];
      echo $document[$value['id_category']]['name_document'];
    }
```